# Transformation of matrices in 3 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The transformation *T* is represented by the matrix
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & -1 & 3 \\
        -1 & 4 & -2 \\
        3 & 2 & 4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
The plane has equation $2x-y+3z=-6$
Show that the image of the plane under *T* is a line and find Cartesian equations of this line.

Let $x=s$ and $z=t$, then $y=6+2s+3t$
I know that the general point on the plane is:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
          s   \\
          6+2s+3t   \\
          t   \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Under transformation *T*, it becomes:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -6 \\
        24+7s+10t \\
        12+7s+10t \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$x=-6$, $y=z+12$
But I am not sure how to show that it is a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here, note that $s$ and $t$ do the same thing.  $7s+10t=k$ neatly replaces all instances of $s$ and $t$ with $k$ (you get $(-6, 24+k, 12+k)$) so there is only one true degree of freedom, so it's a line.

Comment: I get your point but is there a more formal way to show that it is a line (e.g. using general Cartesian equation of a straight line)?

Comment: $(-6,24,12) + (0,1,1)k$ like that?

Comment: I learnt that a straight line in 3D can be written as $$\frac{x-a}{b}=\frac{y-c}{d}=\frac{z-e}{f}$$

Comment: I've got bad news on this one then.  That form only works for lines that are not parallel to one of the axial planes (if it is parallel, then $b$ $d$ or $f$ will be $0$, causing divison by $0$ problems).  This line is parallel to the $y-z$ plane, so $b$ will be $0$.  The more common form of the line in higher spaces is the parametric form I used above, for this reason.

Comment: Oh, and.  Your form is equivalent to $\ell(t) = (a,c,e) + (b,d,f)t$ in this parametric form.